# Unable to validate more than the first entry in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate a form using Javascript but as of right now, it is validating the first form entry and ignoring the rest. If I have less than 6 characters, it'll stop the form from submitting. Once I add more characters, it'll act like the form is fine and submit it, even if everything else is wrong.

HTML:

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return validator(this);">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="userName">Username:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
    <!-- USERNAME --><input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="Username"maxlength="50">
    <p id="userNameEmsg"style="margin:0px;color:red;font-weight:bold;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="Password">Password:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
    <!-- PASS1 --><input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password"maxlength="50">
    <p id="password1Emsm"style="margin:0px;color:red;font-weight:bold;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="Password2">Re-enter Password:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
    <!-- PASS2 --><input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password"maxlength="50">
    <p id="password2Emsg"style="margin:0px;color:red;font-weight:bold;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
    <!-- FIRSTNAME --><input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name"maxlength="50">
    <p id="firstNameEmsg"style="margin:0px;color:red;font-weight:bold;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
    <!-- LASTNAME --><input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"maxlength="50">
    <p id="lastNameEmsg"style="margin:0px;color:red;font-weight:bold;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="zipCode">Zip Code:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
    <!-- ZIPCODE --><input type="text" class="form-control" id="zipCode" placeholder="Zip Code" maxlength="10">
    <p id="zipCodeEmsg"style="margin:0px;color:red;font-weight:bold;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number"maxlength="12">
    <p id="phoneNumberEmsg"style="margin:0px;color:red;font-weight:bold;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="inputEmail">Email Address:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
    <!-- EMAILADDRESS --><input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="email@address.com"maxlength="100">
    <p id="emailEmsg"style="margin:0px;color:red;font-weight:bold;"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group"><!-- BUTTONS -->
                <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
function validator(form) {

var userName = document.getElementById("userName");
var password = document.getElementById("Password");
var password2 = document.getElementById("Password2");
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");
var email = document.getElementById("inputEmail");

var passwordFormat = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
var emailFormat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

if (userName.value.length < 6) {
    document.getElementById("userNameEmsg").innerHTML = "Must have at least 6 characters.";
    return false;
}

else if (password.value.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("password1Emsg").innerHTML = "Please enter a password.";
    return false;
}

else if (!password.value.match(passwordFormat)) {
    document.getElementById("password1Emsg").innerHTML = "Enter correct password format.";
    return false;
}

else if (password.value != password2.value) {
    document.getElementById("password2Emsg").innerHTML = "Passwords do not match.";
    return false;
}

else if (email.value.length < 1) {
    document.getElementById("emailEmsg").innerHTML = "Please enter an email.";
    return false;
}

else if (!email.value.match(emailFormat)) {
    document.getElementById("emailEmsg").innerHTML = "Enter correct email format.";
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}
}
```

I have removed all the elses and have removed the return statement at the bottom and it made no difference to how it funtioned.

Comment: Why do you use javascript instead of the builtin html form validation?

Comment: it's for school

Comment: Can you also put your html code so that we can see it?

Comment: Give an example for password and email please

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the `else if` clasues, replace them by pure `if` and remove the return statement.

Now your code at least, will run through and display all error messages, instead of only the first one.

Now you will need a flag, that signifies, that your form is invalid and disables the Submit button:

```
function validator(form) {

  var userName = document.getElementById("userName");
  var password = document.getElementById("Password");

  var isFormValid = true;

  if (userName.value.length < 6) {
      document.getElementById("userNameEmsg").innerHTML = "Must have at least 6 characters.";
      isForValid = false;    
  }

    if (password.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("password1Emsg").innerHTML = "Please enter a password.";
      isForValid = false;
    }

    /**check if form is Vald **/
    if(!isFormValid){
       //disable submit button
    }
}
```

But if you can avoid it: use as much, of the built-in function of html as possible. There is no reason you could not just use

```
<input type="email" id="emailField" required />
```

and then call `document.getElementById('emailField').checkValidity();`